# How can i execute jquery/javascript inside echo php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

this is my page :
[image]

I want to fill datalist with the content (`<option>.....</option>`) of #hidden datalist.

"#hidden" is generated with php :

```
echo '<datalist id="hidden">';
while ($donneesnom = $reponsenom->fetch()) {
echo '<option value="' . $donneesnom['nomproduit'] . '">';
}
echo '</datalist>';
```

all "td" are generated with php aswell.

I want to fill datalist id=2426 with all options of datalist id=hidden but i don't understand why jquery is not executed. If i do `$("#hidden").html();` in console once page is loaded i have all my options.
If i replace `$("#hidden").html();` by `console.log("test")` it works. I tried to set a javascript timeout on `$("#hidden").html();` but it doesnt work.

Anyone can help me please ?

Comment: Your `<option>` tag is incomplete

Comment: what do you mean ? `</option>` missing ?

Comment: Yes, `</option>` missing as well as anything that would show to the user

Comment: Because your PHP server does not speak JavaScript let alone JQuery. And there is no DOM there for JQuery to do anything, you're still messing around with strings.

Comment: @RiggsFolly according to https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp i don't need </option> and anyway, i don't know why but once page loaded </option> appear...

Comment: First of all, please go read [ask]. Code relevant to your problem belongs directly into your question, in text form & properly formatted. Don’t just show images _of_ code.

Comment: _“If i do $("#hidden").html(); in console once page is loaded i have all my options”_ - then wait until everything is loaded within your code as well …? That is what `document.ready` is for. https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: @04FS It doesn't work better with document.ready

Comment: `$("#hidden").html()` just _reads_ the HTML of that element - it doesn’t _do_ anything with it. If you want this to be inserted into another element now - then you still have to do the actual inserting part. For example by calling the `html()` method on that target element, and passing in the HTML you read from the other element as parameter.

Comment: @04FS You are right, there is no part to insert this in datalist id=2426... Sorry! I will fix my code